# Is there no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the Standard?

Tags: c++, this, this-pointer, implicit-parameters

Recently, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824507/does-a-constructor-also-have-an-implicit-this-parameter/71831996#71831996) question where one of the answers [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71824699/15545927):

> **There's no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the standard.** The standard calls it an "implicit object parameter".

Then someone [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824507/does-a-constructor-also-have-an-implicit-this-parameter/71831996#comment127056409_71824699) that:

> There's no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the standard." **seems wrong**. From [expr.call#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4): "If the function is a non-static member function, the **`this` parameter of the function** shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type conversion."

Seeing the above comment i think that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71824699/17881448) is technically incorrect because the answer said that *"There's no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the standard."* while the standard clearly talks about the *this parameter*.

So how to interpret this further (pun intended)? I mean, it seems that the standard makes a distinction between the non-static member function and a constructor in the context of *`this` parameter*. For example, the standard says that for a non-static member function, the `this` parameter of the function shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call converted as if by an explicit type conversion. But the standard doesn't say the same for constructors. So **why does the standard makes this distinction?**  I mean why doesn't the standard says that constructors also have an `this` parameter that get initialized by the passed argument just like for non-static member functions. This again leads to the deeper question that if there is no `this` parameter in the constructor unlike non-static member function, then how are we able to use `this` inside the constructor. For example, we know that we can write `this->p = 0` inside the constructor as well as inside a non-static member function, where `p` is a data member. But in case of non-static member function, `this` is a parameter of that particular member function so `this->p` makes sense. But in case of constructor `this` is not a parameter, so how are we able to use `this->p` inside the constructor.

Originally, by reading the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824507/does-a-constructor-also-have-an-implicit-this-parameter/71831996#71831996), I thought that the implicit `this` parameter is an implementation detail. But after reading [expr.call#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4) it seems that it is not an implementation detail.

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. Is it the title or the bolded sentence?

Comment: If you have to say "pun intended", it's probably not a very good pun :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I disagreee. `this` has 2 meaning in that sentence. Just to emphasis(so that if someone only got the pun but not the other meaning) on that, i wrote "pun intended".

Comment: @PasserBy I have added some more explanation(example in particular) to clarify my question(if not already).

Comment: @Anya, I believe that is the very *definition* of "pun", two different meanings. I'm pretty certain (because of my warped mind from years of doing cryptic crosswords) I would have gotten it even without the assist, but I digress :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you think `this` is some sort of implicit parameter, type in this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct SimpleThing {
    int xyzzy;
    SimpleThing(): xyzzy(42) {}
    void print(int plugh, const int twisty) {
        std::cout << xyzzy << '\n';
        std::cout << plugh << '\n';
        std::cout << twisty << '\n';
        xyzzy = 0;
        plugh = 0;
        twisty = 0;
        this = 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    SimpleThing thing;
    thing.print(7, 99);
}
```

Then examine the errors you get:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void SimpleThing::print(int, int)’:
prog.cpp:12:16: error: assignment of read-only parameter ‘twisty’
   12 |         twisty = 0;
      |         ~~~~~~~^~~
prog.cpp:13:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   13 |         this = 0;
      |                ^
```

Note that the first two assignments work because they are modifiable variables. The third fails because it is, of course, (non-modifiable) `const`.

The attempted assignment to `this` doesn't look like *any* sort of "can't write to some sort of variable" diagnostic because it actually *isn't.*

The `this` ***keyword*** is a special marker inside non-static member functions (and constructors/destructors) that is translated into the address of the object being worked upon. While it *may* be passed as a hidden parameter, that is very much an implementation detail with which the standard does not concern itself.

The controlling section in the C++20 standard is in `[class.this]`:

> In the body of a non-static member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

Nowhere in there (the entire section) does it mention that `this` is some sort of hidden parameter to the call.

---

And, regarding your question on why there is a distinction between non-static member functions and constructors, I don't believe this distinction involves the *existence* of `this` in either case, it instead has to do with the *qualification* of the type of `this`. It's existence in a constructor is undeniable as `[class.ctor]` states:

> During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, ***from the constructor’s this pointer,*** the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified.

In other words, I see your quote:

> If the function is a non-static member function, the this parameter of the function is initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type conversion.

as specifying only the qualification of `this`, something that the constructor doesn't need.

There is no discussion of cv-qualified conversion for constructors as there is for other member functions because you can't actually *create* a cv-qualified constructor. It would be rather useless if your constructor were not allowed to set any member variables, for example :-)

While constructors can be used to *create* cv-qualified objects, the constructor itself is not cv-qualified. This is covered at the end of `[class.this]`:

> Constructors and destructors shall not be declared `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile`. [Note: However, these functions can be invoked to create and destroy objects with cv-qualified types - end note]

And further in `[class.ctor]`:

> A constructor can be invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. ***`Const` and `volatile` semantics are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the
> constructor for the most derived object ends.***

---

To be honest, I think WG21 would be better off going through the next iteration and replacing things like "the `this` parameter of the function" with a phrase that does not mention parameters at all (such as "the `this` property".

Comment: I had no question about *"why there is no cv qualified conversion for ctors like there is for member functions"*. My question was that *"why standard doesn't say that ctors have `this` parameter just as the standard says that non-static member functions have `this` parameter"*. So i think that section/part of your answer is not needed since i already know about it.

Comment: @Anya, I believe the distinction being made here here is not whether or not a non-static-member-function/constructor *has* a `this`, it's the qualified *type* of the `this`. The former gets a cv-qualified type, the constructor does not. There's no doubt that a constructor *has* a `this`, `[class.ctor]` states: "During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor’s this pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified". Will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quotation from [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (bolding for emphasis, and to answer the question, is mine):

> ##### 10.3.3 The using declaration      [namespace.udecl]
>
> …
> <sup>16</sup>    
> For the purpose of forming a set of candidates during overload
> resolution, the functions that are introduced by a *using-declaration*
> into a derived class are treated as though they were members of the
> derived class. In particular, ***the implicit this parameter*** shall
> be treated as if it were a pointer to the derived class rather than to
> the base class. This has no effect on the type of the function, and in
> all other respects the function remains a member of the base class.
> Likewise, constructors that are introduced by a *using-declaration*
> are treated as though they were constructors of the derived class when
> looking up the constructors of the derived class …

However I should add that the cited paragraph doesn't *seem* to be present in [this later Draft Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl). In fact, that (later) Standard seems to use the phrase, "implicit **object** parameter," in [similar clauses](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#funcs).

So, maybe you should add a specific *version* tag to your question: [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), as there appears to be a divergence in the use (or not) of the term.

---

Note that the above citation is the **only** occurrence of the phrase, "implicit this parameter" in that Draft Standard.

---

Also, note that both documents I have linked are only **Draft** versions of the respective Standards, and both come with this cautionary escape-clause:

> Note: this is an early draft. It’s known to be incomplet and
> incorrekt, and it has lots of bad formatting.

Comment: In my question i had given a [link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4). So my question is about that version of the standard. You can add the respective tag to my question by looking at [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4) draft. It seems to me that the draft is of C++17 standard(by looking at the date on the first page of the draft). Also **there are 3 mentiones of the phrase `this` parameter in [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4) draft.**

Comment: @Anya • I counted 3 occurrences of "this parameter" in n4659, and of those, 1 occurrence of "implicit this parameter".  And 23 occurrences of "implicit object parameter".  I didn't check n4861 or n4910, which may be relevant if someone tidied up the wording.  The constructor's `this` **keyword** is a bit of an oddity when inheritance, multiple inheritance, and virtual inheritance is involved.

Comment: @Eljay [n4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) has 2 occurences of the phrase `this` parameter. I also think that if the implicit `this` parameter is indeed an implementation detail, then the standard should clearly says so. I know that during overload resolution, "implicit object parameter" comes into play. But at 2 places the standard also used "this parameter" which seems to imply that non-static member functions does have an implicit this parameter and it is not just an implementation detail.

Comment: @Anya • It doesn't *seem to imply* that to me.  But I'm not a language lawyer.

Comment: @Eljay The statement *"If the function is a non-static member function, the `this` parameter of the function shall be initialized with a pointer to the object of the call, converted as if by an explicit type conversion."* clearly implies that non-static member function have a `this` parameter otherwise what is being initialized here?

Comment: @Anya • There is a section in the n4659 called "expr.prim.this" which explains what `this` is.  Whether or not `this` is a parameter appears to me to be an implementation detail.  I have worked with compilers where `this` (as an implementation detail) was relied upon by the C code that interoperated with the C++ code.  I've also worked with compilers where `this` was not passed in as a parameter (like other parameter in the C ABI), but rather was held in a CPU register.  Although perhaps that compiler was not compliant, if your conjecture is correct.