# Do all well-known C++ compilers implicitly pass "this" pointer as the 1st parameter to member functions?

Tags: c++, this

I found a "trick" from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665284/6425715) to cast any type into another type by using:

```
template<typename OUT, typename IN>
OUT ForceCast(IN in)
{
    union
    {
        IN  in;
        OUT out;
    }
    u = { in };

    return u.out;
};
```

Then I tried the code below:

```
class C1
{
    public:
    void Test(void)
    {
        std::cout<<"Hello!"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   C1 obj;
   void* function = ForceCast<void*>(&C1::Test);
   ((void(*)(void*))function)(&obj);
   
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with MSVC without errors, and it ran as expected with an output of `Hello!`.

As I know, C++ compilers will implicitly pass `this` pointer into member functions. And the answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254774) in the last 2 paragraphs says all ABIs that the author heard of do pass the `this` pointer as the 1st parameter.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it true that modern C++ compilers, including those for embedded systems (like ARMCC etc), pass the `this` pointer as the 1st parameter?
2. I want to use this "trick" to build an easy-to-use and low overhead callback system without using the "heavy" `std::function`. If the 1st question is true, is there any other potential side effect with this "trick"? (Sample code: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64c051cd6fa3e405))

Comment: your trick is undefined behavior no matter if the answer to 1 is yes or no.

Comment: one issue is that in standard c++ type puning vs unions is not allowed

Comment: It is strongly not recommended, though you can use code that relies on UB as long as you are aware of the consequences. Perhaps the most important is that no matter how much you test this, it can break tomorrow without any notification.

Comment: pretty sure [this section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.funcs#general-2) guarantees the first parameter will be the this parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- I don't think so; "it is considered" means only that, **for purposes of overload resolution**, the compiler will pretend that there's an additional argument. That makes it easier to describe how overload resolution works. Even if it did impose a requirement, the "as if" rule says that it doesn't really have to be there; there's no standard-conforming code that can detect it.

Comment: @PeteBecker ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.  That's why I just left a comment.  Not 100% sure

Comment: @NathanOliver -- I'm 100% sure. <g> But your comment got 4 upvotes!

Comment: You can still use old way instead of `std::function`: `void(*func)(void* userData) = [](void* self) { reinterpret_cast<C1*>(self)->Test(); }; C1 c1; func(&c1);`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830347/12002570) and also [Is there no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902433/is-there-no-such-thing-as-implicit-this-parameter-in-the-standard)

Comment: @Sneftel There was no need to reopen the question. The two dupes mentioned above, answer this question.

Comment: @user12002570 The OP was not asking about the C++ standard. While one of the answers on one of those questions does briefly discuss real-world ABIs, it does not do so in detail. See the currently accepted answer as an example of a useful answer to this question which would not have fit those questions.

Comment: @Sneftel OP explicitly asked *" is there any other potential side effect with this "trick"..."* and the answer is provided by the dupes(that it is UB) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring whether or not it's guaranteed for now (somebody else can certainly give you the details on what the standard say, and what other compilers do) - even practically, just on MSVC, you have one problem. The x64-windows calling convention does pass "this" as the first argument, however there is one major difference between a member-function and a free function:

In case of a return-value, that cannot be returned in RAX, a pointer has to passed to the function. In the case of a free-function, MSVC mandates that this pointer is passed as the first register (RCX), and all other arguments get shifted by 1.
For a member-function, this pointer has to be passed in the first register after the "this" argument (RDX), and all other arguments are shifted by 1.
I know this because I recently implement the native x64-calling convention for my JIT compiler, and ran into the exact same problem - where I had to change up the order of parameters for return-handling, depending on whether it's a member or a free function.

Pretty much means that, what you attempt cannot be generalized, even on just MSVC - it will never work to implement something like std::function, which has to deal with different types of return-values). That is not even talking about other issues with member-function pointers not actually being regular pointers at all - MSVC will for example make those pointers larger, when multiplex/virtual inheritance is in play, where more data is required to fixup "this".