Is the implicit parameter of a member function `this` or `*this`?
I was told that member function of a C++ class has an implicit parameter this which is a pointer to the object. But it seems to me that this parameter should be the object, not a pointer to it. For example, the overloaded operator + in expression obj1 + obj2 has its left operand as the first parameter of operator+ member function, which is the object obj1 instead of its address. So I would like to be confirmed whether the implicit parameter of a member function in C++ is *this or this.

The implicit parameter is the pointer this.

this is a pointer, hence using this->

Why does that matter? If you want to access it, it's exposed as this - a pointer. Whatever magic is applied when calling a function should not be a concern of programmer unless they write a compiler.

@wohlstad: if so, why this parameter in operator+ is changed from this to *this?

@zzzhhh sorry I don't understand what you mean.

@zzzhhh nothing is changed. The signature can be thought of as operator+(Object* this,const Object& other) and the implementation takes care to call it

@Yksisarvinen: It matters because this is not only used in function body. It's also used in matching of overloaded functions.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: so you mean C++ treats matching of normal functions and matching of member functions differently? That is, when calling member function, C++ standard uses special code to change pointer this to *this?

@wohlstad No, implicit this parameter is not an actual c++ standard thing(atleast until c++17). Instead the correct term is implicit object parameter which is *this or X& or const X& etc.

Dupe: Is there no such thing as "implicit this parameter" in the Standard?

Another dupe: Does a constructor also have an implicit this parameter

"I was told that member function of a C++ class has an implicit parameter this which is a pointer to the object...." That is not technically correct but an implementation detail. Beginner c++ books simplify things for beginner but many things are not technically correct in those books etc.

@user12002570 I didn't mean that this is necessarily a standard thing (the question is not tagged language-lawyer anyway). But practically speaking you can still use this->... in any non static method, as if it was a parameter (and the word "implicit parameter" captures this idea). Am I wrong ?

@wohlstad Yeah, informally many times this is said to be the implicit parameter.

@wohlstad here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902608/4117728 it is explained that the implicit this has impact on overload resolution

@user12002570: what my question focuses is how the implicit parameter is used in function matching, not how the implicit parameter is used inside function body. So please don't make my question as dupe because it is totally irrelevant to your question. Also, I think your question linked is actually a dupe. I did not mark it just because I don't have enough score.

@zzzhhh You asked *"confirmed whether the implicit parameter of a member function in C++ is this or this...." and the answer is that technically there is implicit object parameter of type X& but that only comes into play during overload resolution.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: so you think the declaration of member function (operator+ say) should be A operator+(A *, const A &), right? But user12002570 thinks the declaration should be A operator+(A&, const A &). Which one is correct? PS, I'm using C++17.

".. thinks the declaration should be A operator+(A&, const A &)" did they say that? I dont understand what you mean. Anyhow, frankly you still dont get the point. Apart from some arcane cases where the implicit this has an impact that matters for you, it does not matter at all. It is an implementation detail you need not care about. The implementation does it so that you can use this inside member function and for the most part it is irrelevant how the implementation achieves that. Why do you care how operator+ is implemented internally?

@user12002570: I agree with you because that's my suspicion that it is the "implicit object parameter" that is used for function matching. I'm just a bit confused (by beginner's simplified text as you said) so I ask the question for a confirmation. But 463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer clearly suggests that the implicit parameter is the pointer this instead of the "implicit object parameter" *this. So, can you (or anyone else) please don't mark dupe or downvote my question because I think there is much to discuss.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: user12002570 said it clearly above that implicit object parameter is *this. My understanding is that he means it is such the implicit object *this that is used for function matching, not the pointer this suggested in your answer.

@zzzhhh See this answer in the dupe that also says "An implicit object parameter is only relevant to overload resolution, it doesn't "become" this. "

@user12002570: that finally answers my question. Two key words: "Separately" and "The implicit object parameter is part of the rules of overload resolution". Thank you all.

@zzzhhh sorry, I find coments of 120 often confusing and cannot always follow. They started with "No, implicit this parameter is not an actual c++ standard thing" so I didnt look further. Anyhow, if your question is about overload resolution you should mention that in the question

this needs to come from somewhere, that's what is usually called "the implicit (this) parameter". this is a pointer, *this is a reference to the object.
It is implicit, because how it is actually done under the hood is an implementation detail. As pointed out in a comment, it makes no difference whether the implementation implicitly passes the object or a pointer, what you get is this and *this in either case (and a pointer is of course cheaper to pass).
For example when you call
foo->method();
bar.method();

this can be thought of as
method_impl(foo);
method_impl(&bar);

Same for operator +:
a + b;

is (for class types)
a.operator+(b);

which can be thought of as
operator+_impl(&a,b);


As my comment of the question, does C++ standard treat matching of normal functions and matching of member functions differently? That is, when calling member function, C++ standard uses special code to change pointer this to *this to find the best match?

@zzzhhh it is unclear what you mean. Overload resoltution takes into account the signatures as you write them down. The thingy about "implicit parameter" is a mental model to help understand where this comes from, but has no impact on what is a "best match"

@zzzhhh actually I was wrong and it does have an impact on overload resolution, though its a subtle arcane effect. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902608/4117728. To properly answer your question a concrete example would help. And I am still not sure if you are talking about overload resolution. Do you?

Yes, I'm talking about overload resolution (function matching).

@zzzhhh • Yes, I'm talking about overload resolution (function matching).  It would be helpful to provide a [mcve] about what you are talking about, because what you understand and/or misunderstand is not clear to me.
